# What is the best way to slice from psd to Android XML

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, photoshop

I have a sophisticated design for an Android app and designed using Photoshop.

The app has many drawings and curves which mean I can't use Android Studio to develop it there.

I know there are many ways to slice in Android, but I can't find the best way yet to finish the job quicker and with a higher quality.

Comment: "which mean I can't use Android Studio to develop it there": why not?

Comment: A lot of textures and I have to export it as images because I can't draw it manually through Android Studio

Comment: without graphical representation it is difficult to explain do and don`t here

Comment: Try to use xml to do design in android. If you add too much images, the application size will be high.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm worried about and the performance will be much more lower.

Answer (score 4):

The VERY BEST solution - use Zepline online service: https://zeplin.io/ .
It is, this service authomatically calculates all dimensions in 'dp' (you don't have to calculate everything manually)- just select widget and see margins, space between elements, etc. But, the MOST useful thing, is that it converts your pictures into .png files to drawables for ALL densities. It releive you from pain of scanling up and down all pictures.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: what if the design is done in illustrator or any other prototyping software?